# Unable to print with Process()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to print a PDF-file with the following code:

```
try
{

    using (Process myProcess = new Process())
    {
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Labels");
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Test.pdf";
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\Zebra_Technologies_ZTC_ZD420_203dpi_ZPL";
        myProcess.Start();
        myProcess.WaitForExit(10000);
        //myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
        myProcess.Close();
    }

} catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

When omitting `myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments` the file opens in a new window.
If not omitted the exception says:

> The file
>   /Users/me/MyWebsite/Labels/\My-MBP\Zebra_Technologies_ZTC_ZD420_203dpi_ZPL
>   does not exist.

How do I tell the process both which file to print and what printer (USB connected) to use?

My development environment is MacOS, if that means anything.

Comment: Double-backslash’ed paths to access a remote resource is a Windows thing. You can’t simply do that on macOS or Linux.

Comment: @yaakov I see... Do you know how I can do it then?

Comment: It seems that the direction of the slash is not correct, you have both `/` and  `\ `, try to change it all to `/` in your code